# Best web based video player HD - h264?

Tags: web-applications, video-streaming, h.264, flash

I'm looking for a web player with the following features :
- Play h264 in HD
- Feeware
- Good buffering control

Actually, I'm using JwPlayer but it doesn't support buffering !

Comment: Doesn't support buffering?  I'm pretty sure it does (however your question is 2 years old, maybe it's been implemented since you asked).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally like ["Flowplayer"](http://www.flowplayer.org/) as it offers plugin-extension-points.. It also supports streaming ([RTMP](http://www.flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/rtmp.html) and [pseudostreaming](http://www.flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/pseudostreaming.html)) as well as [clustered streaming](http://www.flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/cluster.html) for load-balancing scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the [iMect Player](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&extid=1697043) (written by a hungarian guy) to play videos, it has a lot of great features (incl. pseudo-streaming):

- Elastic: completely resizes itself
  to any environment in real time.
  Aspect ratio, resolution, etc: no
  matter.
- Highly customizeable: you
  can design your own skin files
  without any ActionScript knowledge,
  plus you can re-colour existing
  skins.
- Plays any Flash video
  including H264 with normal, FMS or
  pseudo-streaming.
- Plays live video,
  Ustream.tv API is built-in (can play
  Ustream.tv channels).
- JSON input,
  JavaScript API.
- Multiple video
  support with nice slidebar.
- Detailed
  statistics support, plus Google
  Analytics built-in.
- Has the common
  features: mail form, embed form, info
  pane, full-screen, etc.
- Pre and
  post-roll plus overlay ads.
- Free for
  non-commercial use under a Creative
  Commons license. Very cheap for
  commercial projects.

Answer (score 1):

I think Flash already supports H264.

Flash is still the best if you really want a good web based solution. Another option may be SilverLight3.

Oh, if you are fine with JwPlayer, you may consider try [Dash Media Player](http://www.tmtdigital.com/project/dash_player) + Drupal.

Comment: I know, but I don't want to programm it myself (I've no idea about flash programming) ! I'm looking for a finished player that supports the required features !

Comment: Then try Dash Media Player, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not difficult to make a flash-based video player using Flex. But it's important to note that unless you have a streaming server, all the videos will be downloaded to your clients and stored in their cache. Which depending on the videos which are being viewed, could break their terms of use / copyright.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this HTML5/Flash hybrid player called [darkOnyx](http://darkonyx.web-anatomy.com/en), so my visitors can watch my website on mobile devices too. Player automatically detects whenever someone got flash or html5 compatible browser (you can pick up which works as your primary one). Multi-channel playlist is a huge advantage too.